# Is there a better method to apply some operation on a group of properties?

Tags: c#, reflection

Not sure this is the place for question like this, but give a try anyway.
Say my web api is returning some really wide response (e.g. 900 properties), in the object, I have these:

```
public class WideOutput{
     public datetime Date1 {get;set;}
     public decimal Value1 {get;set;}
     ....
     public decimal Value20 {get;set;}
     public datetime Date2 {get;set;}
     public decimal Value21 {get;set;}
     ....
     public decimal Value40 {get;set;}
     public decimal SomeOtherValues {get;set;}
     public decimal SomeOtherValues860 {get;set;}
}
```

This is the requirement:

1. For properties Value1 to Value20, apply exchange rate from Property
   Date1
2. For properties Value21 to Value40, apply exchange rate from
   Property Date2
3. For other properties, just output raw value.

Of course I could do this:

```
var output = SomeService.LoadWideOuput();
var exchangeRateFroDate1 = ExchangeService.GetRate(output.Date1);
var exchangeRateFroDate2 = ExchangeService.GetRate(output.Date2);
output.Value1 = output.Value1* exchangeRateFroDate1 
....
output.Value20 = output.Value1* exchangeRateFroDate20

output.Value21 = output.Value1* exchangeRateFroDate21 
....
output.Value40 = output.Value1* exchangeRateFroDate40
```

However, that method will be really long and very boring to write.

Another way I can think of is using attribute and reflection. Something like this:

```
public class WideOutput{
     public datetime Date1 {get;set;}
     [ExchangeField(LinkedTo="Date1")]
     public decimal Value1 {get;set;}
     ....
     [ExchangeField(LinkedTo="Date1")]
     public decimal Value20 {get;set;}
     public datetime Date2 {get;set;}
     [ExchangeField(LinkedTo="Date2")]
     public decimal Value21 {get;set;}
     ....
     [ExchangeField(LinkedTo="Date2")]
     public decimal Value40 {get;set;}
     public decimal SomeOtherValues {get;set;}
     public decimal SomeOtherValues860 {get;set;}
}
```

Then in the method I could do this (pseudo code idea only):

```
var output = SomeService.LoadWideOuput();
var exchangeRateFroDate1 = ExchangeService.GetRate(output.Date1);
var exchangeRateFroDate2 = ExchangeService.GetRate(output.Date2);
var exchangeRateDate1Fields = ReadAttributesRelatedAndReturnPropertyList(typeof(output), "Date1");
SetPropertyValueUsingReflection(exchangeRateDate1Fields, output, exchangeRateFroDate1);
var exchangeRateDate2Fields = ReadAttributesRelatedAndReturnPropertyList(typeof(output),"Date2");
SetPropertyValueUsingReflection(exchangeRateDate2Fields , output, exchangeRateFroDate2 );
```

Technically it will work, but as I use reflection to set value, it certainly will be slower. In a web API environment, I do need to pay attention to performance.

I am wondering maybe there are some other ways that I haven't explored?

Comment: The first thing I think of is a Strategy pattern with a Factory. You use the strategy to create different ExchangeRateCalculators based on your scenarios and then you use a Factory to instantiate the strategy you need for the particular data you are working with.

Comment: in that factory, you will still have to either repeat that exchange rate statement 20 time or use reflection to do it, isn't it?

Comment: @daxu This sounds more like a problem with your data structure than an algorithm problem. If you break the data down into two arrays (one for the data to be used with `Date1` and another for the data to be used with `Date2`), this becomes two simple `for` loops, and there's no need for reflection.

Comment: hi @MikeHofer, that is a really good point. I will give a try